# Eclipse can't find my main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run my first Eclipse Java project but for some reason Eclipse can't find `main`.

I created a new Java run configuration and added my project's source file directory to the user entries under the classpath tab.  Then I added my main class `DisplayDeck` to the `main` class field under the main tab.  When I run my project I get the following error.

> Error:  could not find or load main class DisplayDeck.

Here is my code:

```
package cards;

public class DisplayDeck {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck cardDeck = new Deck();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                card tempCard = cardDeck.getCard(i, j);
                System.out.format("%s of %s", tempCard.rankToString(tempCard.getRank()), tempCard.suitToString(tempCard.getSuit()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've read a few similar questions on here but none of the solutions to those questions seems to be working... Something else I noticed is when I choose the search button next to the `main` class field under main in the build configuration there's no classes to choose from in the `listView`.

Comment: Do you have a main method? Show code

Comment: package cards;

public class DisplayDeck {

 statick void main(String[] args){
 Deck cardDeck = new Deck();
 
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
   card tempCard = cardDeck.getCard(i,  j); 
   System.out.format("%s of %s", tempCard.rankToString(tempCard.getRank()), tempCard.suitToString(tempCard.getSuit()));
     
    }
  }
 }
 }

Comment: I've added the code you've pasted as a comment into your actual question - in the future be sure to include the code there instead of comments, since it has the ability to look nicer.  Note that I've copied it *verbatim*, including that misspelling of "static".  If that's not central to your issue, you are encouraged to edit this question to remove that particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code snippet you have `static void main(String[] args)` and not `public static void main(String[] args)`.
This is why main is not found.

From http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/main.html :

> The method signature for the main() method contains three modifiers:
>   public indicates that the main() method can be called by any object. Missing Page covers the ins and outs of access modifiers supported by the Java language: public, private, protected, and the implicit, friendly.
>   static indicates that the main() method is a class method. Class Members vs. Instance Members later in this lesson talks in more detail about class methods and variables.
>   void indicates that the main() method has no return value.
>   The main() method in the Java language is similar to the main() function in C and C++. When you execute a C or C++ program, the runtime system starts your program by calling its main() function first. The main() function then calls all the other functions required to run your program. Similarly, in the Java language, when you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method. The main() method then calls all the other methods required to run your application.
>   If you try to run a class with the Java interpreter that does not have a main() method, the interpreter prints an error message. For more information see Troubleshooting Interpreter Problems .
>
> Arguments to the main() Method
>
> As you can see from the code snippet above, the main() method accepts a single argument: an array of Strings.
>
> ```
> public static void main(String args[])
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. works fine now.   Comming from C++ it seems strange to have to put access modifiers in front of each function/field...

Comment: In future, please attribute, and quote, your sources correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.